# Where is the implementation of abstract forEach() of Stream interface?

Tags: foreach, java-stream

**Iterable forEach():[No Confusion]**
As I know that forEach() is a default method and defined inside Iterable Interface.

```
 default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(action);
        for (T t : this) {
            action.accept(t);
        }
    }
```

So while I write code like below above defalut method gets executed.

```
items.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));
```

**Stream forEach(): [Confusion]**
As I know that forEach() is an abstract method and declared inside Stream interface.

```
void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action);
```

While I write code like below which implementation gets executed?
Asking because as per my understanding below lambda expression will only be executed while action.accept(t) will be invoked.

```
items.stream().forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));
```

Comment: I don’t understand your confusion. The Stream interface has tons of abstract methods, `forEach` is just one of them. These methods are implemented by the class[es] implementing the interface (there can be more than one), the usual way. There is no relevance to the fact that another, unrelated interface has a method of the same name and type.

Comment: @Holger My question here is, while executing below code, implementaion of which class is executing?

items.stream().forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));

Comment: Just try `items.stream().forEach(item -> Thread.dumpStack());` if you think that this implementation detail matters. But, as said, there can be more than one implementation and which implementation will be used may depend on factors not included in your question. The actual type of `items`, for example.

Comment: @Holger Thank you very much, FYI items is a list having some elements. Using dumpStack I can see that implementation provided in java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head is getting executed.

I can understand your point that "methods are implemented by the class[es] implementing the interface (there can be more than one), the usual way".  But in the above case I was just curious about which implementation is getting invoked, because I was not able to find the implementation class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Stream.forEach()` implementation is in the `java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline` class. This class is package private and hidden from the public API.